# SQL Server on Azure VM Slow Network

Tags: sql, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I'm running  SQL Server on Azure VM (Size DS_15).  The server is extremely fast.  My queries are extremely fast.

When I run my application (it's legacy VB 6) from another Azure VM it's extremely fast.  When I run the same application and same identical queries from outside of the Azure DataCenter it's at least 10-15 seconds slower.  I'm using ODBC Data Sources (again, it's legacy) but can't seem to do anything to speed up the connections.

When the slow connections are running SQL Profiler just spits out the same extremely fast data points.  I'm struggling to find where to look next to try to speed these connections up?

When I run some of the trouble queries manually in SSMS with STATS on they return in 0, 0, and 4 ms.  The same queries when ran through the app are taking 140, 130, and 280ms.

Comment: VB 6 do you mean A6 size VM?

Comment: No, the legacy app is VB6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the SQL ODBC driver.  Make sure your driver is up to date, Version 17.